# How to create library (.so or .a files) from C++ project for Android?

Tags: android, visual-studio, java-native-interface

I'm beginner programming with native code on Android.

I have read some guides on the internet, and I knew how to use existing library (.so or .a) file in Android project. I did it by creating JNI interface and call back function in .so (.a) libraries.

My problem is that i have a project under Visual Studio C++, and now I want to build that C++ project become library files (.so or .a) for Android can reuse it.

Someone can show me how can i do it?

Thank you so much!

Phong Le

Answer (score 4):

Android version of .so and the same created by others have no significant differences. You can simply create a .so using gcc (Thats what NDK internally calls) and reuse it with Android.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but can you give me the link for guides about this?

Comment: here is one http://blog.jeffscudder.com/2008/04/creating-and-using-so-files-with-gcc.html. Note that if you are using windows, you may need cygwin to enable gcc running with your project.

Comment: Thank you, but I encountered the problem. That is my C++ code also use another library (ffmpeg). So I don't know how to compile it. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: I see, ffmpeg is another beast in itself and building it for Android has its own steps. I havent dont tried it, Google a bit or post another question with SO so that others who have tried can help you :)